# Panel Bar Text Spacing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

The below snippet is not adding spacing as expected after each field I am adding to a PanelBar.  I am using MVC 4 .net 4.5 Razor View Engine.

It Displays something like this

```
MyTitleNumber:1By:John Doe
```

I want

```
MyTitle   Number: 1   By:  John Doe
```

Or

```
   MyTitle

   Number: 1   By John Doe
```

How can I add correct spacing?

EDIT: The `if` is inside the Razor View

```
if (MyItem.Item != null)
{
branch.Add().Text(MyItem.Title + "    Number:" + MyItem.Number + "    By:" + MyItem.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below :

```
@Html.Raw(
    branch.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Text(Myitem.Title + "<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>" + "Number:" + Myitem.Number +
                              "<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>" + "By:" + Myitem.Name))
```

Comment: Tried that and the if is inside the Razor View that snippet above is inside the Razor View not controller

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you edited your question. It looks like you're using Kendo UI. I'll update answer later.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I am using a kendo ui panel bar to display the items.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
branch.Add().Text(htmlString).Encoded(false);
```

and use `&nbsp;` or a fixed width `<span>` in `htmlString` to create the whitespace.
Also see http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#methods-append